# Other modules functions

Tags: 7, hooks

Is it possible to have a function call within one module which calls a function of a different module even if that function has not been defined as  a hook?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can call all function is write in file .module. If function don't write in file .module. You need use function [module_load_include](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/7) and you can call it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. In your .module file, first load the module name in which your function exists, then, the name of that file. For example:

module_load_include('your_file_extension','your_module_name','your_file_path');
for better undersatnding:

```
module_load_include('inc','module_name','includes/file');
```

and there should exist a folder name include and in this folder put your "file.inc"

and call this function inside [hook_init](https://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_init/7).